# remove black unwanted area in Landsat image using Matlab

Tags: matlab

Please I need to remove the black area in my Image using a Matlab script. [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new matrix with the dimensions of the rotated grey image. Get each from the original image that you want to keep and put it into the corresponding location of the new matrix. Save the new matrix as an image. Done.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please provide a code script for your solution. Thanks in advance